# Python Requests made in parallel but receives responses sequentially

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping, python-requests, python-asyncio, aiohttp

this is the first time I am posting a question. Sorry if the way I present my question is not clear. Basically, I spent the whole day trying to figure out why I am not able to receive responses simultaneously even though my requests were made simultaneously.

I'm using aiohttp now but I've also tried threading and concurrent requests but the results were all the same.

Each requests takes about 1.2s to process but if all of them are running in parallel shouldn't I get all of the responses within 2s? However, it still takes ~6s to complete 5 requests which is as good as running it synchronously. What am I doing wrong here?

Code:

```
async def makeRequest(session,rsrcID, date):    
      RVT = str(getFromFile()[1])
      cookie = str(getFromFile()[0])
      #update RVT and cookie values      
      start = time()
      async with session.post(    
            url='https://rbs.xxx.edu.sg/SRB001/GetTimeSlotListByresidNdatetime',
            data = {
            "__RequestVerificationToken": RVT,
            "rsrcID": rsrcID,
            "rsrctypID":"0ef480d2-9b9f-4654-bd73-8d0d946b7152",
            "bookingstatus":"Available",
            "SearchDate": date,
            "SearchStartTime":"07:00",
            "SearchEndTime":"22:00",
            "BKG_RUL":"false",
            "IS_SLD_Resource":"false"
            },
            headers = {
                        'authority': 'rbs.xxx.edu.sg',
                        'method' : 'POST',
                        'path' : '/SRB001/GetTimeSlotListByresidNdatetime',
                        'scheme' : 'https',            
                        'accept': 'application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01',
                        'accept-encoding' : 'gzip, deflate',
                        'accept-Language': 'en-US,en;q=0.9',
                        'content-length' : '398',
                        'content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8',
                        'cookie' : str(cookie),
                        'origin' : 'https://rbs.xxx.edu.sg',            
                        'referer': 'https://rbs.xxx.edu.sg/SRB001/SRB001Page',                   
                        'sec-fetch-dest' : 'empty',
                        'sec-fetch-mode' : 'cors',
                        'sec-fetch-site' : 'same-origin',
                        'user-agent' : 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/87.0.4280.88 Safari/537.36',
                        'x-Requested-with' : 'XMLHttpRequest',   
                    },
      ) as availableTimesResponse:      
          end = time()
          print(end-start)
          availableTimesResult = await availableTimesResponse.json(content_type=None)
          #store all the timeslots from 1 into a single list
          timeSlotList = []
          for timeslot in availableTimesResult:
                timeSlotList.append(timeslot['SLT_Time'])
          return timeSlotList

roomIds = ['85b977b4-46f3-4bde-96fe-59380e1be257', '598d9d46-5a2d-4fef-8517-2624b380a7ee', '7970b6d4-7e88-46ba-b8f7-0e107e0befbf', 'f0965fad-df04-4539-a79a-2feb29df311e', '07470cb3-f79c-468f-a332-644e621edd7e', '7e24d0c0-6a90-4e24-8f16-41e69193ceb3']

async def main():
    async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
        return await asyncio.wait([makeRequest(session,roomid, '18 Dec 2020') for roomid in roomIds])

asyncio.run(main())
```

Comment: Your question is reasonably clear and the code _should_ run in parallel. Is it possible that the server itself is serializing the requests or is simply unable to process them at a faster pace? You can try running five parallel requests with `curl` or other independent tool and see what's going on.

Comment: I tried running your code, and so far the requests are done in parallel. However, i tried httpbin.org endpoints instead of those in your question.
As @user4815162342 mentioned, it could really be an issue with the server.

Try doing a `start - end` check in your `main()`, to compare the duration of individual requests and the `main()`. In my case, it was about a milisecond longer than the longest request